# Firing scroll function only on screen size > 720

Tags: jquery

I have a scroll function that makes the navbar bigger on scroll and smaller when the user is at the top of the page. When the screen becomes smaller the navbar is transformed in a collapsible nav and the function is not working properly when this is the case.

I want to nest the function within a function that checks for the screen size. When the screen size is > 720 the scroll function needs to be fired, else it needs to return.

Currently I got the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 720) {
        window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
        function scrollFunction() {
            if (document.body.scrollTop > 40 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 40) {
            document.getElementById("navbar-search").style.height = "100px";
            document.getElementById("navbar-search").style.marginTop = "-35px";
            }
            else {
            document.getElementById("navbar-search").style.height = "62px";
            document.getElementById("navbar-search").style.marginTop = "0px";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I do not get any errors and the function is still working fine on every screen size. Can someone explain me why it is not checking for the screen size and is still firing the function no matter what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plain javascript pendant of `$(document).ready()` is `window.onload`. So when the page is loaded at first time and the width is greater than 720 pixels the event handler will be set.

If you rezize the window and the width is 720 pixel or smaller the event onScroll is still active. The solution is you have to remove the event `window.onscroll`.

It exists an event called `window.onresize` ([see here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp)) that you can use to check if the window size has being changed. In case the size is smaller then 720 pixels remove the event handler.

Proberbly it will be better you bind onscroll event on an dedicated element and not on window.